# How to get top 2 for each category without using rank/row_number functions in ms-sql

Tags: sql-server

I am on MS-SQL 2016.

I have a scenario that requires to get top 2 paid bonus for each group, **RANK and ROW_NUMBER** are not allowed, here is the code you can use to generate the table and data:

```
Create table Freelancer (id int, fl_name varchar(20), bonus int, fl_group varchar(50))


insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (1, 'John', 1000, 'SQL')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (2, 'Jane', 990, 'MySQL')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (3, 'Jimmy', 320, 'Oracle')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (4, 'Jeff', 802, 'DynamoDB')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (5, 'Johnathan', 2345, 'Hive')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (6, 'Jeffery', 321, 'RDS')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (7, 'Jane2', 1990, 'MySQL')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (8, 'Jimmy3', 321, 'Oracle')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (9, 'Jeff4', 803, 'DynamoDB')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (10, 'Johnathan5', 345, 'Hive')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (11, 'Jeffery', 32, 'RDS')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (12, 'Jane3', 1190, 'MySQL')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (13, 'Jimmy4', 322, 'Oracle')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (14, 'Jeff5', 8002, 'DynamoDB')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (15, 'Johnathan6', 235, 'Hive')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (16, 'Jeffery7', 31, 'RDS')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (17, 'Jack', 34, 'Redshift')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (18, 'Jennifer', 121, 'Aurora')
insert into Freelancer (id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values (19, 'Jackson', 425, 'Redis')
```

The expected result is for example in group **DynamoDB**, **Jeff5(8002) and Jeff4(803)** would be picked up

What I tried already is below and not returning the needed result despite I specified top 2 in the clause:

```
select *
from Freelancer t
where t.ID in (
    select top 2 ID
    from Freelancer tt
    where tt.fl_name = t.fl_name
    order by tt.bonus desc
    )
order by fl_group, bonus desc
```

my result:

[image]

Comment: Can you use other window functions?

Comment: Did you really need to cross post? [How to get highest bonus and second highest bnus paid freelancer for each group](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-highest-bonus-and-second-highest-bnus-paid-freelancer-for-each-group#post-3713595) What was wrong with the answers you were getting on SSC?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this solution, hear in this solution I have consolidated fl_group as your category, and get fl_group wise top 2 records.

**Declare temp table**

```
declare @Freelancer as TABLE (id int, fl_name varchar(20), bonus int, fl_group varchar(50))
```

**Insert Sample data**

```
insert into @Freelancer(id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group) Values(1, 'John', 1000, 'SQL')
,(2, 'Jane', 990, 'MySQL')
,(3, 'Jimmy', 320, 'Oracle')
,(4, 'Jeff', 802, 'DynamoDB')
,(5, 'Johnathan', 2345, 'Hive')
,(6, 'Jeffery', 321, 'RDS')
,(7, 'Jane2', 1990, 'MySQL')
,(8, 'Jimmy3', 321, 'Oracle')
,(9, 'Jeff4', 803, 'DynamoDB')
,(10, 'Johnathan5', 345, 'Hive')
,(11, 'Jeffery', 32, 'RDS')
,(12, 'Jane3', 1190, 'MySQL')
,(13, 'Jimmy4', 322, 'Oracle')
,(14, 'Jeff5', 8002, 'DynamoDB')
,(15, 'Johnathan6', 235, 'Hive')
,(16, 'Jeffery7', 31, 'RDS')
,(17, 'Jack', 34, 'Redshift')
,(18, 'Jennifer', 121, 'Aurora')
,(19, 'Jackson', 425, 'Redis')
```

**Category-wise Top 2 Records**

```
select *
from @Freelancer t
where t.ID in (
    select top 2 ID
    from @Freelancer tt
    where tt.fl_group = t.fl_group
    order by id
    )
order by fl_group,id
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Here, you can also use join instead of the subquery to improve your query performance.

For More information, you can try this solution Please Visit this URL: [Query Editor](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21e1e581ce9a95238c24d854cbe87133)

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it would make a little bit more sense if the final order is on fl_group and then Bonus in desc. But that can be easily done based on your script:)

Comment: Thanks mdivk, Please mark this answer if it helps you, so others also can learn and get answers of this kind of questions.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**, and clearly is reporting the wrong results.  The highest bonus for group DynamoDB is 8002.

Comment: Hi Tim, You are right at your place, Actually, in the above answer I have ordered records based on the  fl_group and id but you can understand where we can apply order based on our need, in this case, we also need to include bonus column as well, but I think it should be understandable, we can change as per our need, this is just sample hint or way to archive such requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be comparing bonuses between the outer query and subquery, and you should be correlating using the group.

```
SELECT *
FROM Freelancer t
WHERE t.bonus IN (
    SELECT TOP 2 tt.bonus
    FROM Freelancer tt
    WHERE tt.fl_group = t.fl_group
    ORDER BY tt.bonus DESC
)
ORDER BY
    fl_group,
    bonus DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use other windowed functions, try to replace `ROW_NUMBER()` behaviour with windowed `SUM()`:

```
SELECT 
    id, fl_name, bonus, fl_group
FROM (
    SELECT 
       *,
       SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY fl_group ORDER BY bonus) AS Rn
    FROM Freelancer
) t
WHERE Rn <= 2
```

Comment: most of the posted answers are getting the expected result, I cannot take all as answer but thank you for the enlightening

Comment: @mdivk Yes, only one answer can be accepted. I'm glad you have a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery which returns for each row the number of rows having greater bonus in that group:

```
select t.* from Freelancer t
where 1 >= (select count(*) from Freelancer tt where tt.fl_group = t.fl_group and tt.bonus > t.bonus)
order by t.fl_group, t.bonus desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fc8112a8f5189b500d9ed3a3fb76f1c).
Results:

```
> id | fl_name    | bonus | fl_group
> -: | :--------- | ----: | :-------
> 18 | Jennifer   |   121 | Aurora  
> 14 | Jeff5      |  8002 | DynamoDB
>  9 | Jeff4      |   803 | DynamoDB
>  5 | Johnathan  |  2345 | Hive    
> 10 | Johnathan5 |   345 | Hive    
>  7 | Jane2      |  1990 | MySQL   
> 12 | Jane3      |  1190 | MySQL   
> 13 | Jimmy4     |   322 | Oracle  
>  8 | Jimmy3     |   321 | Oracle  
>  6 | Jeffery    |   321 | RDS     
> 11 | Jeffery    |    32 | RDS     
> 19 | Jackson    |   425 | Redis   
> 17 | Jack       |    34 | Redshift
>  1 | John       |  1000 | SQL
```

Comment: most of the posted answers are getting the expected result, I cannot take all as answer but thank you for the enlightening

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT f2.*
FROM Freelancer f CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (2) f1.* 
       FROM Freelancer f1
       WHERE f1.fl_group = f.fl_group
       ORDER BY f1.bonus DESC
     ) f2
ORDER BY f2.fl_group, f2.bonus DESC;
```

Comment: most of the posted answers are getting the expected result, I cannot take all as answer but thank you for the enlightening